# How do I remove the Add to Cart button from Wishlist based on specific products?

Tags: product-attribute, addtocart, wishlist

I have already removed the "Add to Cart" button from both the Product Detail page and the Product List/Grid Page based on an attribute.

I now need to be able to remove the button from Wishlist and compare for those specific products based on an attribute, but can't find the button construction anywhere for these two pages.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't test for this here? `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/button/tocart.phtml`

Comment: use xDebug and you will know everything

Comment: @gtr1971 that file contains the button constructor for the 'Add All to Cart' but not the 'Add to Cart'

Comment: Yep, I noticed that after Frank posted his answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> app/design/frontend/[package]/[your
>   template]/template/wishlist/item/column/cart.phtml

Check in there, you can remove the button from there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

to remove Add To Cart button number 1 : 
open your path

> /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/wishlist/item/column/cart.phtml

or

/app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/default/template/wishlist/item/column/cart.phtml

comment line 37

```
<?php if ($product->isSaleable()): ?>
   <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" onclick="addWItemToCart(<?php echo $item->getId()?>);" class="button btn-cart"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<?php else: ?>
```

becomes

```
<?php if ($product->isSaleable()): ?>
   <!-- <button type="button" title="<?php //echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" onclick="addWItemToCart(<?php //echo $item->getId()?>);" class="button btn-cart"><span><span><?php //echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button> -->
<?php else: ?>
```

to remove Add All To Cart button number 2 :
open your path

> /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/wishlist/button/tocart.phtml

or

/app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/default/template/wishlist/button/tocart.phtml

comment line 29

```
<?php if($this->getWishlist()->getItemsCount() && $this->getWishlist()->isSalable()): ?>
  <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add All to Cart')) ?>" onclick="addAllWItemsToCart()" class="button btn-add"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add All to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif;?>
```

becomes

```
<?php if($this->getWishlist()->getItemsCount() && $this->getWishlist()->isSalable()): ?>
  <!-- <button type="button" title="<?php //echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add All to Cart')) ?>" onclick="addAllWItemsToCart()" class="button btn-add"><span><span><?php //echo $this->__('Add All to Cart') ?></span></span></button> -->
<?php endif;?>
```

[image]

the final result

[image]